# On dispersion of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d. random variables.
I am interested in the quantity
$$m(X):=\mathbb{E}[X|X>Y] - \mathbb{E}[X|X < Y].$$
It is not hard to see that $m(X) \geq 0$ and that $m(X) = 0$ if and only if $X$ is a constant, almost surely.

So, one may think about $m(X)$ as measuring the dispersion of $X$ in a sense.

My question is there a relation between $m(X)$ to other known measures of dispersion such as variance of mean absolute deviation?

Comment: If $Y$ is a constant $y$ and $\mathbb P(X<y) = \frac12$ and $\mathbb P(X>y) = \frac12$ and  $\mathbb P(X=y) =0$ (i.e. $y$ is a median of $X$ but $X$ is almost surely not $y$) then $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X>y] - \mathbb{E}[X\mid X < y] = 2\mathbb{E}[|X-y| ]$, i.e. double the *mean absolute deviation about the median* of $X$.

Comment: This is obviously true. However, I'm interested in the case where $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ (only independent).